# Performance of Class methods vs singleton instance methods

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app, I'm using both strategies:

1. I have a `Utils` class, it only has class methods that I call for doing common global methods, like `NSString` validation, etc.
2. I have an app-wide singleton class which I instantiate during app Did Finish Launching, and use this throughout the app to hold global objects / state, perform long-running processes, etc.

My question is, in the terms of *performance* which approach is better? I'm happy with both the approaches, but I can do an inexpensive, but effortful migration to move all the Utils class methods to instance methods in the app-wide singleton if this would give me performance gains. The Utils methods get called a *lot* in my app, but I don't really notice any performance penalties in Instruments.

Likewise, I can go the other way and move at least a few of the somewhat general purpose functions I end up adding to the singleton to now be class methods in the `Utils` class as well.

Does any Objective-C guru have some concrete benchmarks or even strong opinions on which approach is more performant?

Comment: Since classes are objects and singletons are objects, all you're doing is calling methods on objects, and calling methods on one kind of object shouldn't be noticeably faster than calling methods on another kind of object. Class methods are not the “static methods” known from other languages such as Java which are more like plain old C functions in Objective-C.

Comment: @amon: However, to call instance methods on the singleton, he would presumably have to call something to "get" the singleton object, which is another call; whereas for calling a class method, the class object is provided directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with if you really need to shave those extra few nanoseconds off your `Utils` C++ functions (potentially inlined) are probably the fastest thing on offer to you.

As to the question of whether class methods or singleton instance methods are more performant I will not claim to know for sure but a quick look at the [objective-c runtime shipped with OSX 10.10](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-646/) shows that `_class_getClassMethod` calls `_class_getInstanceMethod` which might lead you to think that instance methods would be faster.

Looking into this further I found that `_object_getMethodImplementation` calls `_class_getMethodImplementation`. Which would point to class methods being slightly faster to load.

All this is pretty moot though as in any instance you have 1 or 2 more function pointer accesses. This would only be noticeable if your methods are being called at least millions of times (and at that point optimising your method implementations is probably time better spent).

Stylistically, I agree with what you currently have, using singletons where state is required and class methods where it is not.

Comment: They're called a lot, but more in the tune of hundreds of times, definitely not millions. Marking your answer as accepted, thanks! :)

Comment: A class is an object and there is no difference in the process of sending a message to an object between if the receiver is a class or not. Every method is an "instance method" of some instance. Every method call goes through `objc_msgSend` (or related functions), and does not call any of the functions you listed above. However, there is a difference before the call in that a singleton object needs to be gotten somehow whereas a class object is known and hard-coded at compile-time.